Baseball - Fielder's choice or an error during double play?
Runner on the first base. Batter hits a ground ball to shortstop. Shortstop throws to second, second to first in an attempt for 6-4-3 double play. However, first baseman fumbles the ball, and as a result, the batter runner is safe on first. Lead runner is out on 6-4.
Did batter reach first on fielder's choice or an error by the first baseman? Or both? Does it matter how close the call would be if the first baseman made the catch successfully? If so, is it up to the official scorer to make that call? Can the first baseman be charged with an error on a double play attempt? Does anything change if the error was a wild throw by the second baseman instead?

The relevant rules here start with 9.12(d)(3)

(d) The Official Scorer shall not charge an error against:
...
(3)  any fielder who makes a wild throw in attempting to
complete a double play or triple play, unless such wild
throw enables any runner to advance beyond the base
such runner would have reached had the throw not been
wild;

This suggests that we will not penalize the fielder that rushes a throw trying to pick up the double play throwing (a bit) wild.   It probably lead to the common phrase you can't assume a double play.
But it says nothing about the fielder receiving the throw.  So moving on to the comment on this rule:

Rule 9.12(d) Comment: When a fielder muffs a thrown ball
that, if held, would have completed a double play or triple play,
the Official Scorer shall charge an error to the fielder who drops
the ball and credit an assist to the fielder who made the throw.

So while a bit of leeway is given for rushing things in a double play, it's not a blanket okay to the fielders after getting one out.  Assuming the throw from second was accurate, this sounds like an error to me.
Yes it's up to the official scorer.  Yes the first baseman can be charged with an error on the back half of a double play attempt.  Yes things change if the throw by second was wide.
I would score this as
R1: out 6-4
B: GIDP reached on E3

Since the runner is judged to have grounded into a double play, remember no RBI would be awarded if there had been a runner on third. 9.04(b)(2) applies.  And this scoring rule makes it explicit that we can award errors on a double play.

(b) The Official Scorer shall not credit a run batted in
...
(2)  when a fielder is charged with an error because the fielder
muffs a throw at first base that would have completed a
force double play.

